# SQL type=time column has unexpected date of 1970-01-01

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I am using mssql package with node.js to retrieve data from sql-server by executing the following SP.

```
USE [InductionProgram]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SelectAllRequests]    Script Date: 9/2/2019 10:33:34 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectAllRequests]
AS
SELECT * FROM dbo.Trns_Request

GO;
```

The column in question is of type `time` and in side sql-server they appear as follows
`15:00:00.0000000`

However when retrieved through by executing the SP with an mssql connection from node server the resulting value for the above time would be as follows

`1970-01-01T15:00:00.000Z`

What could be the reason for this, I understand the date is the start of the unix epoch, what I don't understand is how this particular date is encoded in the above time and how to get rid of this.